# In C# how can I serialize a List<int> to a byte[] in order to store it in a DB field?

Tags: c#, generics, list, serialization

In C# how can I serialize a `List<int>` to a `byte[]` in order to store it in a DB field?

I know how to serialize to a file on the disk, but how do I just serialize to a variable?

Here is how I serialized to the disk:

```
            List<int> l = IenumerableofInts.ToList();
            Stream s = File.OpenWrite("file.bin");
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(s, lR);
            s.Close();
```

I'm sure it's much the same but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead of the file stream:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream();
```

This will place the data in the `s` variable, which you can read later on in your application.

In order to read from it, you will need to set the `Position` to 0, so seeking will start from the beginning of the stream (if reading in chunks), or use `ToArray()` on it to retrieve the complete content.

Comment: For someone new to MemoryStream it's important to also point out that you'll have to set the Position back to 0 before reading from it.  That's often overlooked and causes new devs some head scratching.

Comment: @Sam - thanks for the comment. Answer updated with this info.

Comment: @Sam.  Incorrect.  You can use the `.ToArray()` method to get the contents of the MemoryStream regardless of position.

Comment: @Jason Punyon, `.ToArray()` will copy the data to a new array whereas setting the `.Position` to zero gives you access to the underlying data directly without an extra copy.

Comment: @Sam: Agreed.  I'd think it'd just be easier to get the Array representation (that's what the Q is about) of the bytes and dispose of the stream immediately.

Answer (score 3):

To put it bluntly: I would put them in another table in the database that has a one-to-many foreign-key relationship with its parent record.

That way, you can do normal DB operations with them, like retrieving parent records based on which ints are in the child table.

Comment: +1. Even if you serialize it to XML and store it as an XML column type (in SQL Server), you're still better off for searching/retrieval/reporting than if you use binary serialization. And normalized tables are generally a better choice than that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would *not* use `BinaryFormatter` for this purpose - it is implementation specific and overly expensive. I would be tempted to (one of):

1: use `BinaryWriter` / `BinaryReader` to do it manually (but note that this is easy to interpret from any API):

```
    // note I've used arrays in the example; lists are identical
    int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    byte[] raw;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
    {
        writer.Write(data.Length);
        foreach(int i in data) {
            writer.Write(i);
        }
        writer.Close();
        raw = ms.ToArray();
    }
    // read it back
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(raw))
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
    {
        int count = reader.ReadInt32();
        data = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            data[i] = reader.ReadInt32();
        }
    }
```

or 2: use an implemenation-independent serialization format, such as protobuf; here I'm using protobuf-net

```
    int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    byte[] raw;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, data);
        raw = ms.ToArray();
    }
    // read it back
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(raw)) {
        data = Serializer.Deserialize<int[]>(ms);
    }
```

Note that (1) uses 24 bytes for the example (6 * 4 bytes); (2) uses 10 bytes (in part because the numbers are simple, but actually protobuf has some tricks (such as "packed" data) that we aren't even using here).

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic serializer

```
private static string SerializeObject<T>(T source)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, source);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/10/04/xmlserializer-and-invalid-xml.aspx

Comment: @Jason - on the wire, there isn't a vast amount between them.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I won't wrestle with the master over serialization, but even for a list of an object that has a goodly number of verbosely named properties?

Comment: @Jason - oh, absolutely *xml* is overkill - heck, tsv / csv etc would be easier. My point was simply that there is little fundamental difference between strings and bytes. One is largely a subset of the other, obviously, but you know what I mean.